# Por que usar __debugInfo()?

Tags: php, classes, debug, métodos-mágicos, var-dump

Vi que o PHP 5.6 criou agora o método mágico novo, chamado `__debugInfo`.

Esse método tem como finalidade retornar um `array`, para que será imprimido na chamada de `var_dump`. Esse `array` retornado obviamente deve oferecer informações para debug da classe.

Gostaria de entender em que casos isso seria útil?

O `var_dump` tradicional, por si só, já não era suficiente? Será que isso foi feito só para resolver problemas de referências circulares?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando usamos o `var_dump` sem o metodo `__debugInfo` serão exibidos na saída os dados, incluido as variaveis privativas e protegidas, como cita a documentação:

> This method is called by `var_dump()` when dumping an object to get the properties that should be shown. If the method isn't defined on an object, then all public, protected and private properties will be shown.

Então o `__debugInfo` será usado para limitar o que será exibido na saída, um exemplo:

```
<?php
class Foo
{
    private $podeIrParaoLog = 'Olá';
    private $naoPodeIrParaoLog = 'Informação sensivel';

    public function __debugInfo()
    {
        return [
            'private::podeIrParaoLog' => $this->podeIrParaoLog,
        ];
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();

var_dump($foo);

print_r($foo);
```

A saída será algo como:

```
object(Foo)#1 (1) {
  ["private::podeIrParaoLog"]=>
  string(4) "Olá"
}
Foo Object
(
    [private::podeIrParaoLog] => Olá
)
```

Comment: Eu custo entender esse método, em todos meus testes ele não funciona. Até com o seu exemplo não funcionou.

Comment: @BoiProgramador você esta certo, a maioria das pessoas fazem postagens em blogs ou até respostas em outros lugares que não são tão diretas quanto deveriam ser e outra horas eles fazem o contrário, são diretos demais quando deveriam ser mais detalhistas antes de apresentar a parte código, explicando conceitos técnicos necessários. Um dos motivos que me esforço em formular respostas longas e outra horas curtas é para analisar quando um tipo e quando outro é necessário, pois eu penei também pra aprender por culpa de textos ruins que encontrava na internet, então tento fazer melhor para ajudar.

Comment: É por isso que eu dei positivo, dá pra perceber que você entende do assunto e sabe o que está dizendo. Mas obrigado pela resposta, agora que vi que é bem antiga. Mas serviu pra estudo. Obrigado